# Remove-1st function in SCHEME

Tags: scheme

I have to write a program that takes a list and removes the first item, and uses recursion in SCHEME. 
I am just stuck on how to recur it.

so it would have

```
> (remove-1st '(x y z x))
(y z x)
```

Comment: The question is nonsensical as stated, so there must be some other requirement missing from its description.  There's no explanation of why recursion would be necessary for the given task.

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3):

I think I must be misunderstanding your question, but this will work:

```
(define (remove-1st list) 
    (cdr list))
```

No recursion necessary. Indeed, no function of your own, as cdr will do what you seem to want.

Perhaps you need to reformulate your problem? Do you mean that you want to get the remaining items one by one somehow?

Comment: I have to use recursion, it is part of the assignment. That is where I am struggling.

Comment: Then you need a different problem. Recursion is a kind of loop, and a loop makes no sense for this. You're struggling because you _can't_ sensibly use a loop for the problem you describe above.

Comment: I got it! Thanks though! I ended up reversing it, and cons it from there